# Convert thu jul 05 10:30:00 ist 2012 format into 2012-07-11 10:30:00.0 format in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to convert the  jul 05 10:30:00 ist 2012 format into 2012-07-11 10:30:00.0 format.
I have tried the following

```
  String str_date = "Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012";
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date today = null;
try {
    today = (Date) fmt.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Todays date:" + today);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
```

I am getting

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337) error

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

provide same format in following both this error is because format in the string date and the format are not same so make it same sothat it can parse it.

```
String str_date = "Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012";
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

e.g. replace above with following

```
String str_date = "Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012";
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

you can change format as follow:

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-d hh:mm:ss";


String oldDateString = "Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

here d will be your date in old format is : `Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012`

new date is `2012-07-6 10:30:00`

Answer (score 2):

The date and time pattern you have coded doesn't match the string format.

[image: Date and Time Patterns]

See the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for more information.

For parsing `"Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012"` the format should be `"EEE MMM d H:m:s z y"`.

To generate `"2012-07-06 10:30:00.0"` the format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"`.

The full conversion between the two formats would be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d H:m:s z y");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date = sdf1.parse("Fri Jul 06 10:30:00 IST 2012");
assert sdf2.format(date) == "2012-07-06 10:30:00.0";
```